# Nginx deployment with GKE

Tags: nginx, deployment, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm working on a project where I'm deploying a system on Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE). My setup involves using Nginx as a Static File Server/Web Server to serve a React-based frontend, with backend integration as needed. However, I've hit a roadblock with an error during the deployment of my frontend service.

When deploying, I consistently encounter this error:

`exec /docker-entrypoint.sh: exec format error`

I believe this might be related to my Configuration file of the Nginx, the Dockerfile or the way I'm setting up my Kubernetes deployment. I'm hoping to get some insights or suggestions on how to resolve this.

Thanks a lot in advance

This is how the Dockerfile is looking like

```
FROM node:latest as build
WORKDIR /app
COPY . ./
RUN npm install && npm run build

FROM nginx:stable
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y nginx-extras libnginx-mod-http-headers-more-filter
RUN rm /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
COPY --from=build /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

This is the Nginx configuration file

```
server_tokens off;
more_clear_headers 'Server';

server {
  listen 80;
  root /usr/share/nginx/html;
  index index.html index.htm;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }
}
```

This is the deployment file

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: frontend-service
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: frontend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: frontend
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: frontend-container
        image: [REDACTED_FOR_SECURITY]
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: [REDACTED_FOR_SECURITY]

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: frontend-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: frontend
  ports:
  - protocol: "TCP"
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80
  type: LoadBalancer
```

Comment: Any chance you are building your Docker image on a Mac with Apple silicon (e.g. an M1 Mac)?

This error usually indicates that you built the image on one architecture and are trying to run it on another.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It was a mismatch between the architecture of the GKE pod and the base base docker image. Fixed now :)